# Symfony use_javascript() routing issue

Tags: symfony1, routes, web-hosting

i am using symfony 1.4.11; use_helper('Url').

On using link_to('new',course/course/type/new),
 the url it show is ../backend_dev/backend_dev/Course/course/type/new 
    instead of 
../backend_dev/Course/course/type/new.
Same issue exist for form_tag also.

Edit

Above issue was solved.By setting no_script_name: true at config and clearing cache.

But image_tag(),use_stylesheet() and use_javascript() gives path as for example

> use_javascript('jquery-1.6.1.min.js') 
>    ==>../web/backend_dev/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js

instead of

> use_javascript('jquery-1.6.1.min.js') ==>../web/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you change your sf_web_dir configuration? What's up with the relative paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without your full routing.yml but the one thing i see is that your internal_uri should be expressed as an abs url with a query string like:

`link_to('new','/Course/course?type=new');`

Note the forward slash at the beginning. Also the module name should be the real module name, not the routed one so if the maodule is /apps/backend/modules/Course then the module in the internal URI should be `Course` not `course` same with the action name.

If the route is named then you should use one of the following:

`link_to('new','@routename?type=new');`

OR

`link_to('new','routename', array('type'=>'new'));`

Comment: +1,thanks for response,Sir.Please consider the Edit part of the question.

Comment: How do you have this configured? backend_dev shoudlnt be a folder it should be a single php file in `web` ie. `backend_dev.php` And your Webserver's (or the virtual host's) should map to your web folder.

Comment: Sir,there is no backend_dev folder .backend_dev.php file is there in web folder.How to map to web folder in server

Comment: Depends on the web server.. if you are using apache then [create a virtual host](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01#chapter_01_web_server_configuration_the_secure_way). I usually use custom hostnames instead of different ports... but whatever you prefer...

Comment: @Bhanu Krishnan: If you haven't mapped it to a backend_dev/ folder then it wouldn't appear to start with. Do you know if this is a out-of-the-box installation of symfony or have you/someone tweaked the symfony config URLs?